# owncloud webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, owncloud

I have Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS server on hyper-v virtual machine.

Mysql 14.14

Apache 2.4.7

php 5.5.9

Owncloud 8.1.3.0

After an unexpected shutdown of vm, main page have redirect loop. All attempts to modify htaccess not successful (i try deleted it, redirect remains). The following configuration of htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
       SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" XAUTHORIZATION=$1
       RequestHeader set XAuthorization %{XAUTHORIZATION}e env=XAUTHORIZATION
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>

  <IfModule mod_env.c>
    # Add security and privacy related headers
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "none"
    Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
    SetEnv modHeadersAvailable true
  </IfModule>

  # Add cache control for CSS and JS files
  <FilesMatch "\.(css|js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value upload_max_filesize 10G
php_value post_max_size 10G
php_value memory_limit 512M
php_value mbstring.func_overload 0
php_value always_populate_raw_post_data -1
php_value default_charset 'UTF-8'
php_value output_buffering off
<IfModule mod_env.c>
  SetEnv htaccessWorking true
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/host-meta\.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^\.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^apps/calendar/caldav\.php remote.php/caldav/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^apps/contacts/carddav\.php remote.php/carddav/ [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^remote/(.*) remote.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates)/.* - [R=404,L]
RewriteRule ^(\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console).* - [R=404,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options -Indexes
<IfModule pagespeed_module>
  ModPagespeed Off
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 403 /core/templates/403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /core/templates/404.php
```

And apache config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        #ServerName *** 

        ServerAdmin ***
        DocumentRoot /var/www/owncloud

        <Directory /var/www/owncloud>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

        LogLevel warn
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/owncloud-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/owncloud-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE oc_storagecharts2;
DROP TABLE oc_storagecharts2_uconf;

rm -rf /var/www/owncloud/apps/storagecharts2
```

This helped me.

Comment: Some explanation of why you need to do that would be beneficial. I imagine you would need to remove the entries in oc_appconfig that refer to storagecharts2 too.